# ¿Qué tipo de variable puedo utilizar para asignar horaEntrada y HoraSalida?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper, apex

Estoy trabajando en un proyecto donde se asignan turnos a los trabajadores que van de 1 a 8 horas, con horario laboral de 8 am a 5 pm,  si al asignar un turno este pasa de las 5pm, se debe asignar el tiempo faltante para el otro día después de las 8 am. Si alguien tiene una idea de como hacerlo agradezco su ayuda. Utilizo **Oracle SQL Developer y PL-SQL**...
Las variables las tengo de la siguiente forma:

````
   hr_fin DATE := TO_TIMESTAMP('17:00:00','HH24:MI:SS');
   ans NUMBER :=1; --hora turno
   v_h_turno date;
   BEGIN
    
     v_h_turno := sysdate + NUMTODSINTERVAL(ans,'HOUR');
     if v_h_turno <= hr_fin then
        UPDATE turno
        SET    fecha_turno= sysdate 
        WHERE  consecutivo = :p_turno;  
     if v_h_turno >= hr_fin then  
        "aquí debería sumar el tiempo que falte al siguiente día"
     end if;
     
    END;```
````